# Session storage for authentication using SailsJS/Node, Mocha, Supertest

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sails.js, supertest, superagent

I have a SailsJS setup and am using Mocha/Supertest/Superagent combination to run unit tests. I have searched around and read about supertest and how it now extends superagent.agent('url') in order to store sessions and cookies. I know that my /athlete/login and /athlete/current routes are working as I can test them using Postman and they return the correct values. However, when testing, I get a 200 status on login but a 404 on /athlete/current

Here is what I am currently working with:

**1. Mocha Test to login and verify session of user logged in**

```
var should = require('should'),
    assert = require('assert'),
    request = require('supertest');

it('/athlete/login should return 200 and athlete on success', function (done){
                var athleteStub = AthleteStub(),
                    setPassword = athleteStub.password;

                Athlete.create(athleteStub, function(err, newAthlete) {
                    var user = request.agent(sails.express.app);

                    user
                            .post('/athlete/login')
                            .send({ 'email': athleteStub.email, 'password': setPassword })
                            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
                            .end(function (err, res) {
                                if(err) return done(err);

                                console.log('test', user );

                                // res.should.have.status(200);
                                // res.body.email.should.equal(athleteStub.email);

                                user
                                    .get('/athlete/current')
                                    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
                                    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
                                    .expect(200)
                                    .end(function (err, res) {
                                        if(err) return done(err);
                                        done();
                                    });


                            });
                });
            });
```

**2. /Login and /current actions**

```
login: function (req, res) {
    var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

    Athlete.findOneByEmail(req.body.email).done(function (err, athlete) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ error: 'DB error' }, 500);
        }

        if (athlete) {

            if ( !athlete.isActive ){
                res.json({ error: 'Your account is not active.' }, 500);
            }

            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, athlete.password, function (err, match) {
                if (err){
                    res.json({ error: 'Server error' }, 500);
                }

                if (match) {
                    // password match
                    req.session.athlete = athlete.id;
                    res.json(athlete);
                } else {
                    // invalid password
                    if (req.session.athlete){
                        req.session.athlete = null;
                    }
                    res.json({ error: 'Invalid password' }, 403);
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.json({ error: 'User not found' }, 404);
        }
    });
},

current: function (req, res){

    if(req.session.athlete){
        Athlete.findOneById(req.session.athlete)
            .where({ isActive: true })
            .done(function(err, athlete) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({ error: 'No active athlete found with ID of '+req.params.id }, 404);
            } else {
                res.json(athlete);
            }
        });
    }else{
        res.json({ error: 'No active athlete currently logged in.' }, 404);
    }

},
```

---

**SOLUTION**

I had changed some of the routing so basically put '/athlete/current/' from above is now '/athlete/me/'

```
            it("/athlete/me should return user data if athlete is logged in", function(done){
            var agent = request.agent(sails.hooks.http.app),
                athleteStub = AthleteStub(),
                setPassword = athleteStub.password;

            agent
                .post('/athlete')
                .send( athleteStub )
                .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
                .end(function (err, res) {
                    should.not.exist(err);
                    res.should.have.status(200);
                    res.body.email.should.equal(athleteStub.email);
                    res.body.firstName.should.equal(athleteStub.firstName);
                    res.body.lastName.should.equal(athleteStub.lastName);

                    agent
                        .post('/athlete/login')
                        .send({ 'email': athleteStub.email, 'password': setPassword })
                        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
                        .end(function (err, res) {
                            should.not.exist(err);
                            res.should.have.status(200);

                            agent
                                .get('/athlete/me')
                                .expect(200)
                                .end(function(err, res) {
                                        should.not.exist(err);

                                        res.body.email.should.equal(athleteStub.email);
                                        res.should.have.status(200);
                                        done();
                                    });
                        });
                });
        });
```

Comment: Hi, have yu find a solution to your problem ? I'm facing same kind of problems. Thank's in advance.

Comment: @jmcollin92 - Nope, still having the same issue. For now, I have just left testing out to make sure my builds pass. I have begun using the latest beta of Sails though and will eventually get around to implementing it again (or at least trying to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you found an answer to this or not but i was able to get the cookie to save with the following code:

```
var agent = request.agent(sails.hooks.http.app);

describe('Session', function(done) {
it("should be able to create", function(done) {


agent
  .post("/session/create")
  .send({email: "test.User1@gmail.com",password: "test", confirmation: "test"})
  .expect('set-cookie', 'cookie=hey; Path=/', done)
  .end(function(err, res) {
    console.log('got a response!! '+ JSON.stringify(res.body));
    done();
  });
});
it("should be logged in", function(done) {


agent
  .get("/user/index")
  .end(function(err, res) {
    console.log('got a response from user/index!! '+ JSON.stringify(res.body));
    done();
  });
  });
});
```

Comment: Needed to bring the agent variable declaration into the it statement but finally got it to work in a very rough state right now. Not sure if it was something that was fixed with the 0.10 beta version of sails/waterline. Will update the OP with my solution for now.